# `mkisofs crashed` while burning a movie to a Blu-Ray with K3b

Tags: video, burning, blu-ray, k3b

#### Problem

I want to burn a movie (.mkv) to a Blu-Ray disc.

#### What I've done

First, I generate a Blu-Ray BDMV directory structure from the .mkv with [tsMuxeR GUI](https://github.com/justdan96/tsMuxer) (2.6.16-dev).

Next, for how to burn to the disc, I'm working off of [this guide](https://www.debugpoint.com/2018/08/burn-blu-ray-disks-ubuntu-linux-k3b/), which recommends using K3b along with the cdrecord writing medium.

I make a Data Project, and add the directories I generated from tsMuxeR, and then begin burning. When the burning hits 50%, the write fails with 'mkisofs crashed', as shown below:

[image: k3b dialogue]

#### Details

I pasted more detailed output from K3b [here](https://pastebin.com/fBCJG5Fx)

#### Question

How can I burn a .mkv file to a Blu-ray Bisk so that I can put it in a Playstation 4 and watch it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be a permissions issue, try opening a terminal and typing these one at a time.

```
sudo chmod 4711 /usr/bin/wodim

sudo chmod 4711 /usr/bin/cdrdao

sudo chmod 4711 /usr/bin/growisofs
```

Also read [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=279918&hilit=regionset)

Comment: I ran `sudo chmod 4711 /usr/bin/wodim; sudo chmod 4711 /usr/bin/cdrdao; sudo chmod 4711 /usr/bin/growisofs` instead and it worked. If you could add the `growisofs` part, I think it could help others using this answer.